# Multiple cell validation in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need help validating multiple cells in Google sheets

I have cells A4-C4 to have red background if empty

and now I want to make it so say, B9 to pop out with message or warning if any of A4-C4 is empty

I tried the validation option of course, but it doesn't have some kind of

> "show message if condition met"

does the red background make it so B9 always think A4-C4 not empty?

Comment: _"i have cells A4-C4 to have red background if empty"_. How to you do that? I suppose you use conditional formatting. Correct? If so, what formula do you use for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IF` function to control this kind of behaviors.

### Approach:

With the `COUNTIF` function you can count the empty cells. You will show the message only if the count is bigger than 0.

### Solution:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A4:C4, "")>0,"There is an empty cell", "")
```

Comment: it still says "The data you entered in cell A14 violates the data validation rules set on this cell" which doesnt make sense to me

Comment: Can you post a sample of your sheet? What is the validation rule in cell `A14`?

Answer (score 0):

Data Validation is applied only to user-entered data. Check this previous similar post.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76414/is-there-a-way-to-force-someone-to-enter-a-non-empty-value-string-in-a-cell-in-g

Comment: yea i looked at that and it didnt really do it. it just gives user warning, doesnt restrict them from entering data in restricted cell